# Comparing values in columns between 2 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a function in `VBA Excel` that reads for example `A1` and continues to read each line until the end of the values in that column, the function will take the value and lookup this value in `sheet2` column `A:A` if indeed it finds the value it will go to the next cell to the right using the `offset()` function. Once it has verified that the values match with the values from Sheet1 it will go to the next row (`A2`) and continue, else if there is a value that does not match it will copy the whole row and paste it on `Sheet3` which will show the values not found in `sheet2`.

This is what I have tried so far however it only copies the first row that does not match and it stops.

```
Sub citi()

Dim oFSO As Object
Dim arrData() As String
Dim taxid(1 To 65000) As String
Dim amount(1 To 65000) As String
Dim tref(1 To 65000) As String
Dim bnam(1 To 65000) As String
Dim bnknu(1 To 65000) As String
Dim bnkagc(1 To 65000) As String
Dim bbnkac(1 To 65000) As String
Dim citb(1 To 65000) As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
arrData = Split(oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\alvaradod\Desktop\citi macro\Import File.txt").ReadAll, vbCrLf)
Sheets("Import").Range("A1").Value = "Tax ID"
Sheets("Import").Range("B1").Value = "Amount"
Sheets("Import").Range("C1").Value = "TReference"
Sheets("Import").Range("D1").Value = "BeneficiaryName"
Sheets("Import").Range("E1").Value = "BankNum"
Sheets("Import").Range("F1").Value = "BankAgency"
Sheets("Import").Range("G1").Value = "BeneficiaryBankAcc"
Sheets("Import").Range("H1").Value = "CitiAcc"
For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
    If Len(arrData(i)) > 0 Then
        j = j + 1
        taxid(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 49, 15)
        amount(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 92, 15)
        tref(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 26, 15)
        bnam(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 257, 34)
        bnknu(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 452, 3)
        bnkagc(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 455, 4)
        bbnkac(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 463, 15)
        citb(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 622, 10)
    End If
Next i

If j > 0 Then
    '' On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Import").Range("A2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(taxid)
    Sheets("Import").Range("B2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(amount)
    Sheets("Import").Range("C2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(tref)
    Sheets("Import").Range("D2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(bnam)
    Sheets("Import").Range("E2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(bnknu)
    Sheets("Import").Range("F2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(bnkagc)
    Sheets("Import").Range("G2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(bbnkac)
    Sheets("Import").Range("H2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(citb)
End If
Set oFSO = Nothing
Erase arrData()
Erase taxid
Erase amount
Erase tref
Erase bnam
Erase bnknu
Erase bnkagc
Erase bbnkac
Erase citb
i = 0
j = 0
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
arrData = Split(oFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\alvaradod\Desktop\citi macro\Export File.txt").ReadAll, vbCrLf)
Sheets("Export").Range("A1").Value = "Tax ID"
Sheets("Export").Range("B1").Value = "Amount"
Sheets("Export").Range("C1").Value = "TReference"
Sheets("Export").Range("D1").Value = "BeneficiaryName"
Sheets("Export").Range("E1").Value = "BankNum"
Sheets("Export").Range("F1").Value = "BankAgency"
Sheets("Export").Range("G1").Value = "BeneficiaryBankAcc"
Sheets("Export").Range("H1").Value = "CitiAcc"
For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
    If Len(arrData(i)) > 0 Then
        j = j + 1
        taxid(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 189, 15)
        amount(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 56, 15)
        tref(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 24, 15)
        bnam(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 204, 34)
        bnknu(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 296, 3)
        bnkagc(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 299, 4)
        bbnkac(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 345, 15)
        citb(j) = Mid(arrData(i), 284, 10)
    End If
Next i
If j > 0 Then
    '' On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Export").Range("A2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(taxid)
    Sheets("Export").Range("B2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(amount)
    Sheets("Export").Range("C2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(tref)
    Sheets("Export").Range("D2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(bnam)
    Sheets("Export").Range("E2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(bnknu)
    Sheets("Export").Range("F2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(bnkagc)
    Sheets("Export").Range("G2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(bbnkac)
    Sheets("Export").Range("H2").Resize(j).Value = Application.Transpose(citb)
End If

Set oFSO = Nothing
Erase arrData

''new code

Dim r As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Set r = Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1), Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
Dim curRowSheet1 As Long

curRowSheet1 = 1

For Each cell In r
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rfind = Sheet3.Range("C:C").Find(cell.Value)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If (rfind Is Nothing) Then
        cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet1.Cells(curRowSheet1, 1)
        curRowSheet1 = curRowSheet1 + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

End Sub

Comment: please can you add a screen print of an example of the data you have in the sheet "Import" ...is it a table of data or just data in column `A`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how my logic would be for this:

1. Loop through Sheet 1
2. For every cell in Sheet 1 column A, go to Sheet 2 and use [Range.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) to search for the value in Sheet1 column A
3. `If (cell Is Nothing) Then ' copy and paste Sheet1 current row to Sheet3`
4. Keep a counter for the current row in Sheet3 and increment it every time you paste a row into Sheet3

Here's a very basic example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub compare()
    Dim r As Excel.Range
    Dim cell As Excel.Range
    Dim rFind As Excel.Range
    Set r = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1), Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Dim curRowSheet3 As Long

    curRowSheet3 = 1

    For Each cell In r
        Set rFind = Sheet2.Range("A:A").Find(cell.Value)

        If (rFind Is Nothing) Then
            cell.EntireRow.Copy Sheet3.Cells(curRowSheet3, 1)
            curRowSheet3 = curRowSheet3 + 1
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

By the way, I should mention that using Range.Find is much, much, much faster than looping through `Sheet2` on your own.

Also, you don't need to reset `rFind` to `Nothing` every time at the end of the loop because `Range.Find` will return `Nothing` if nothing is found, otherwise, it will return a `Range` object.

Comment: No, they can be safely removed

Comment: Hi Joseph4tw, the code seems to work, however I am having the same problem as I was having with my original code that It is pasting the rows with error on A1 therefore it is pasting the data on top of one another which leaves me at the end with the last row with error instead of displaying all lines that do not match.

Comment: @whytheq I think I did it out of habit when I wrote some other "standard" logical piece of code in the past. I forget now what it was for, but nonetheless, they can be removed and I'll update the answer

Comment: @joseph4tw after analyzing the data it seems it returns the values that match, however I am looking for the macro to return the values that do not match with both sheets, do you have an idea of what the change would be?

Comment: @AlfredoA. not sure. The `If` statement only evaluates to true if the cell in Sheet1 is *not* found in Sheet2. Can you edit your question and include the new code?

Comment: @AlfredoA. I don't understand your criticism - this code should only find instances that do not match! I've just tested it and it only moved non matches.

Comment: @joseph4w I have updated the code that I currently working with so that you can take a look at it. Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something to compare two worksheets in two different workbooks, this is a modified version of my code:
It will print every difference between your "Export" sheet and "Import" sheet onto your "Err" sheet.
You have "C2:C25" so I used 25, but if you need more or less columns, change the `numColumns` value.

```
Sub findDifferentCells()

    Dim prevSheet As Worksheet
    Dim currSheet As Worksheet
    Dim writingSheet As Worksheet
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim numColumns  As Integer
    Dim endOfCurr As Integer

    Set prevSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import")
    Set currSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Export")
    Set writingSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Err")
    numColumns = 25

    endOfCurr = currSheet.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    'Compare values of both worksheets:
    For x = 0 To endOfCurr
        For y = 0 To numColumns
            If prevSheet.Range("A1").Offset(x, y).Value <> currSheet.Range("A1").Offset(x, y).Value Then
                writingSheet.Range("A1").Offset(x, y).Value = currSheet.Range("A1").Offset(x, y).Value
            End If
        Next y
    Next x

    'Clean-up:
    Set currSheet = Nothing
    Set writingSheet = Nothing
    Set prevSheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Hope that works for your problem, if not let me know.